# Оптимизация сайта под айфон

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive, width

Я cверстал сайт и опробовал его на всех девайсах, но когда я посмотрел на сайт с айфона, то обнаружил проблему:

[image]

Справа белая колонка появилась, хотя блоки должны быть на всю ширину, если кто знает как это исправить, то, пожалуйста, поделитесь со своим опытом.

[Ссылка на сайт.](http://turon.pronumero.com)

---

К стати я тестил на айфон 6 ретина 1920x1080

Comment: Что-то затисалось в элемент .fastsearch. При чем проблема не всегда реализовывается 100%. Бутстрап такой бутстрап...

Comment: Привет мир! Мой случай с решением [Верстка - отзывчивая: проблемы с браузерами iPhone и Samsung](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558127/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-iphone-%D0%B8-samsung/559772#559772)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в `head` добавить

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

У тебя начиная с ширины `777px` начинает появляться эта область (возьми уменьши ширину экрана браузера) может попробовать  для html, `body` указать ширину `100%`.

Comment: У меня и так стоит

Comment: у тебя начиная с ширины 777px начинает появляться эта область (возьми уменьши ширину экрана браузера) может попробовать  для html, body указать ширину 100%

Answer (score 0):

Вот сюда: `.search-form-block .tour-select` добавляем max-width: 100%