# Верстка - отзывчивая: проблемы с браузерами iPhone и Samsung

Tags: html, вёрстка, iphone, браузер

Привет мир! 
Есть уже готовый проект на PHP 5.6.22 / 1C-Bitrix - надо сделать отзывчивую верстку.

Все ок, но есть проблемы с браузерами телефонов iPhone и Samsung - все выглядит как на обычном ПК, отдаленно.

Сначала спросил [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078778/html-responsive-chrome-mozilla-vs-safari-samsungbrowser), но посоветовали про Битрикс спрашивать в русскоязычном сообществе.

Воспользовался [советами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801685/issue-stopping-iphone-resizing-html-e-mails/24055721#24055721), не помогло:

1. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>`
2. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1/>`

Вот, что-то [похожее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495631/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD/495634#495634)

Спасибо!

Comment: Код в пункте 1 в списке гарантированно должен работать. Вы помещаете его внутрь `<head>`? Возможно потом где-то ниже по коду viewport у вас переназначается битриксом?

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Спасибо, что откликнулись. Да, помещаю в <head>, ниже по коду искал не раз - переназначений не нашел. Речь о сайте http://www.promeli.ru/. Мобильная версия на субдомене http://www.test.promeli.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Причиной стала единственная строчка в коде CSS:
`.wrapper{min-width:auto}` где auto и есть ошибка. Сделал: `.wrapper{min-width:inherit}`

Видимо "auto" не воспринимают браузеры iPhone, Samsung и UCBrowser на Android